# What does this boolean setter mean?

Tags: java

I am assigned some maintenance task for a Java program and found this:

```
public void setActiveCode(boolean isActiveCode) {
    this.isActiveCode = isActiveCode & Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

The type of `this.isActiveCode` is a `boolean`, The same concept is repeated for every boolean setters in the class. I can't figure out why it is done this way and I can't ask the original developer.

Would there be any valid reason for doing this?

Comment: I sure can't think of one. Looks like a prime example of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) to me.

Comment: No. This bears out my theory that all programmers should be forced to memorize de Morgan's laws. Not to mention operator precedence and a few other utter basics.

Comment: What's especially strange is that a single `&` is a bitwise operator, not the normal `boolean` operator `&&`, and the use of `Boolean.TRUE` instead of simply `true`.

Comment: @jpmc26 They are both Boolean operators when the operands are booleans. Nothing strange about it, except the entire thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would there be any valid reason for doing this?

No. This is just *more* verbose code with zero gain in clarity (and arguably a loss in clarity since here you are wondering what it's all about).

It reminds me of

```
public boolean isTrue(boolean b) {
    if(b == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which unfortunately you will see in the wild from time to time. It's just so sad.

Answer (score 1):

Its weird. Booleans can be used with logical `&`, but this is useless because `a & true = a`. Seems to be a developer specific OCD.